# Searching through a tree and adding up the distances of towns you pass by

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

These 2 functions together should return the total distance you must travel to go directly to a node. At the moment, it doesn't work with more long and complex things. Simple things however work just fine.

```
    int Stree::distance(string origin_city, string destination_city)
{
    int total_distance = 0;
    Node *new_root = m_root;
    new_root = find_node(m_root, origin_city);
    total_distance = get_distance(new_root, total_distance, destination_city);
    return total_distance;
}

int Stree::get_distance(Node* cur, int distance, string destination)
{
    Node *tmp = cur;
    if(cur == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(cur->m_city == destination || tmp->m_city == destination)
    {
        //cout << distance + cur->m_parent_distance << endl;
        return distance += cur->m_parent_distance;
    }
    if(tmp->m_left != NULL)
    {
        //cout << "checking left" << endl;
        tmp = cur->m_left;
        return get_distance(cur->m_left, distance, destination) ;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "checking right" << endl;
        return get_distance(cur->m_right, distance, destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some input data for cases that work and for cases that do not, to help us understand what you mean by "long and complex" as opposed to "simple"?

Comment: the input is in another function, that places them all into the tree, this one then looks them up.

Comment: this is what i meant to say at the top of the code::

I am currently working on a function that has 1 helper function, the main function takes in 2 strings and searches for the first one (which becomes a reference as if it was m_root) and a second one to be searched in the tree. once they are searched, my helper function is supposed to search for the 2nd city and count the distance it had to travel as if a truck was going towards that city.

Comment: People on SO will need more information than you've provided if they are to have a chance of helping you. What do you mean by "long and complex" as opposed to "simple" in this context?

Comment: it just means that if you input just 1 or 3 cities, it works fine, but once it has to start checking for more complex trees, it doesnt work.

Comment: In getdistance function, you are always going left when left != NULL. So right tree will not be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: I think the only way your code could loop should be when the tree contains loops - i.e. isn't a tree at all.

Try this debugging helper:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
...
static vector<Node*> visited;

int Stree::get_distance(Node* cur, int distance, string destination)
{
    if (find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), cur) != visited.end())
        throw runtime_error("looping " + cur->m_city);

    Node *tmp = cur;
    if(cur == NULL)
        return 0;

    int ret;
    visited.push_back(cur);
    if(cur->m_city == destination || tmp->m_city == destination)
    {
        //cout << distance + cur->m_parent_distance << endl;
        ret = distance += cur->m_parent_distance;
    }
    if(tmp->m_left != NULL)
    {
        //cout << "checking left" << endl;
        tmp = cur->m_left;
        ret = get_distance(cur->m_left, distance, destination) ;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "checking right" << endl;
        ret = get_distance(cur->m_right, distance, destination);
    }

    visited.pop_back();
    return ret;
}
```